# Securing AzureAD Powershell Module

Tags: azure, security

Is there a way to secure the AzureAD Powershell Module from enumerating other users data without impacting legitimate services like Teams? There are two approaches, but can't seem to make it work without impacting dependent services.

1. Set-MsolCompanySettings -UsersPermissionToReadOtherUsersEnabled $false
2. Register Microsoft Graph in Azure AD + Restrict Permissions